# Changing data on db on a specific day and time - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm

I have a specific requirment for a web application which is build with Nodejs/MongoDb/Express/Angular. Application itself is a application for mentors and has a kind of schema like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },

         username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
        ....

        status: {type: String, enum: ["online", "offline"]},
        schedule: [{
            day: String,
            StartTime: Date,
            EndTime: Date
        }]

                ...


        })
```

Every user has its own schedule, for example working Every: Monday ,Wednesday ,Thursday From: 04:00 PM To: 07:00 PM.

Now, how can I change the status from Offline to Online as they submited their schedule. I mean from the example above, to change Every: Monday ,Wednesday ,Thursday at the specific time the user status on db from "offline" to "online" ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by "change Every: Monday ,Wednesday ,Thursday at the specific time the user status on db from "offline" to "online" "

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, the idea is to let the users submit their schedule and then to run a script or whatever which set their status online according to the schedule they submitted by itself. 
I want to get all the user.schedule and run a cronjob or other tool where I change the user.status to "online" in a specific day&time as they submitted. Am I clear ? @digit

Comment: You mean the status is set when user is on the schedule. For e.g.. let say the user has set the schedule to Every monday. So, the user is online every monday. Is it like that?

Comment: Yeah like that, e.g.. User1 has set the schedule Every Monday from 4PM to 8PM, and the User2 has set Every Tuesday and Thurday from 6PM to 10PM then each of them will have status online on that specific time, so other users can arrange a meeting with them. Clear ? @digit

Comment: Yes. So a user can have more than 1 schedule?

Comment: yeah that's right @digit

Comment: You can but it not the best idea as you will trigger many scheduler . Let say if you have 50 users. A user can have 5 schedule in a week, the total will be 5 x 50 = 250. So, you need to check for 250 schedule . It's not easy though since you also must know when the user offline to trigger the scheduler again. So in this case, you must check both online and offline states.

Comment: @digit OK, what is your suggestion/tip ?